# Magento Invoice Excel Export - How do I change fields?

Tags: php, excel, magento, export

I want to export some invoices to Microsoft Excel / XML. The standard Format doesn't work very well because i need some extra columns.

My question is: Where is the file generated? Where do i set these special columns?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what version of Magento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The export to Excel is performed when the `InvoiceController` calls `getExcelFile()` on the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Invoice_Grid`.  The invoice Grid extends from the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` which in turn calls `_exportExcelItem` on each row of the grid.

The `_exportExcelItem` method uses the grid's `_columns` private variable to export the spreadsheet columns.

All of which goes to say... that the `_prepareColumns()` method in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Invoice_Grid` sets the columns that are displayed in the grid, and exactly the same columns in the Excel export.

If you want to add extra columns, you could rewrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Invoice_Grid` and redefine the `_exportExcelItem()` method with something like this:

```
$this->addColumn('your_extra_field_name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Field Title'),
        'index'     => 'your_extra_field_name',
        'type'      => 'relevant_data_type',
    ));
... rinse and repeat ... then finish with
parent::_exportIterateCollection($callback, array $args);
```

There are numerous posts on StackOverflow and the Intertubes on writing a custom module to extend a Block, grok those and then apply the specifics above.

This is the key piece of XML you need in your config.xml:

```
 <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                 <sales_invoice_grid>Namespace_Modulename_Block_Rewrite_AdminhtmlSalesInvoiceGrid</sales_invoice_grid>
....
```

HTH,
JD

Comment: In which file do i find this code? Sorry, i'm very new to Magento. I searched in the whole /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml folder but didn't find anything.

Comment: Correction: Found the file and testing now :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom report that extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Invoice_Grid` (and the container, `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Invoice`).

The only difference it needs to do is call `parent::_prepareColumns()` then add your own columns. You can also use it's [`addColumnsOrder()`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Adminhtml/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.html#addColumnsOrder) to move them around.

You will also need to make a controller that works like `Mage_Adminhtml_Report_SalesController::invoicedAction()`.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a complete new connection and class to the DB because i didn't get the right files.
Thank you for all your help but this solution was much simpler it saved me about 5 days of work!