# Magento: Editing Sales Invoice Export (CSV) Fields

Tags: php, variables, magento, mage

So I have finally found the file in which to edit the fields I export to CSV for a sales invoice form.  Credit goes to:

[Magento Invoice Excel Export - How do I change fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498790/magento-invoice-excel-export-how-do-i-change-fields)

Now that I am adding fields such as:

```
$this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice #'),
        'index'     => 'increment_id',
        'type'      => 'text',
    ));
```

I am wondering what variables I can use or where the file is I can look for them.  I am trying to get:

- Tax
- Shipping Cost
- SKU
- Discounts
- Shipping Address

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I always have a hard time knowing how to call given variables through Magento.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the class where you also put `$this->addColumn(...)` there should be a function like `prepareCollection()`. You may use everything which is available in this collection. You can even add more fields in this collection...